# Creating a new variable with a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, variables, new-operator

I am having some issues with creating a new variable in my database, based on combinations of other variables, I'm an R beginner so am probably just doing something dumb!

I am trying to ask - if any of the following columns (AC1.int, AC2.int, AC3.int) contain NV, call the corresponding row in the new column "Vehicle noise", likewise for "Vehicle approach", and call everything else "none".

I created a new column called "Vehicle":

```
ACdata$Vehicle <- "NA"
```

Then I tried to do this first with an if/else statement:

```
ACdata$Vehicle <- ifelse(ACdata$AC1.int=="AV" | ACdata$ACN.2=="AV" | ACdata$ACN.3=="AV", "Vehicle approach", ACdata$Vehicle)
ACdata$Vehicle <- ifelse(ACdata$AC1.int=="NV" | ACdata$ACN2.int=="NV" | ACdata$ACN3.int=="NV", "Vehicle noise", ACdata$Vehicle)
ACdata$Vehicle[is.na(ACdata$Vehicle)] = "None"
```

This ran, bu only sometimes populated the correct result in the new Vehicle column. I have no idea why this only worked around a third of the time!

SO I tried a for loop next with the following code:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(ACdata)) {  
  if(ACdata$AC1.int[i]== "NV" | ACdata$ACN2.int[i]== "NV" | ACdata$ACN3.int[i]== "NV") {
    ACdata$Vehicle[i] = "Vehicle noise"} else if (ACdata$ACN1.int[i]== "AV" | ACdata$ACN2.int[i]== "AV" | ACdata$ACN3.int[i]== "AV") {
      ACdata$Vehicle[i] = "Vehicle approach"} else 
        ACdata$Vehicle[i] = "None"
}
```

This didn't run at all and I can't find the issue. Help please! Its there a better way to do this that I've missed? Or am I just missing something in the for loop? Thanks in advance for all of your help!

Comment: Try it again but without the quotes around `NA`; if you use `"NA"`, then `is.na` will always be `FALSE`

Comment: Thanks Allan! I tried that, but it doesn't make any difference to the success of the if else statement, it still only successfully populates some cells, and others are left empty!

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
as_tibble(ACdata) %>% 
  mutate(Vehicle = case_when(
    AC1.int == "AV" | ACN.2 == "AV" | ACN.3 == "AV"~"Vehicle Approach",
    AC1.int == "NV" | ACN.2.int == "NV" | ACN3.int == "NV"~"Vehicle Noise",
    TRUE~"None"))
```

Input:

```
ACdata <- data.frame(
  AC1.int = c("AV", "NV", "KV"),ACN.2 = c("AV","NV", "L"), ACN.3 = c("AV", "NV", "NV"),
  ACN.2.int = c("NV", "NV", "K"), ACN3.int = c("NV", "NV", "K"))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 6
  AC1.int ACN.2 ACN.3 ACN.2.int ACN3.int Vehicle         
  <chr>   <chr> <chr> <chr>     <chr>    <chr>           
1 AV      AV    AV    NV        NV       Vehicle Approach
2 NV      NV    NV    NV        NV       Vehicle Noise   
3 KV      L     NV    K         K        None
```

Comment: Thanks Langtang! I tried this, and it gave me the following warning:

Comment: Warning message:
`...` is not empty.

We detected these problematic arguments:
* `needs_dots`

These dots only exist to allow future extensions and should be empty.
Did you misspecify an argument?

Comment: i don't have your data..can you provide the first 5-10 rows of `ACdata` (only the variables in this question, please)

Comment: the code works, please check again. I've added fake data, since you did not provide

Comment: Thanks so much Langtag! The data you created looks very similar to my data, nice work! I'm still getting the same error message, not sure what is going on there. Do you have any thoughts on another way to this?

Comment: hmm, can you check your version of tibble? is it prior to 3.0.3, by any chance?

Comment: It is, and I just googled this and found that this error happens with versions before 3.0.3. I updated my package and it hasn't updated. I just used the code without as_tibble and IT WORKED!!! So exciting!

Comment: you dont have to use `as_tibble()`. you can just pipe ACdata directly like this `ACdata %>% mutate(...)`

Comment: Oh my goodness! Thank you so much Langtang!! I really appreciate you!!!

Comment: also, i don't see anything wrong with your base r approach. my guess is that you have some rows that don't meet any of the three conditions and that is why some rows remain as NA.  that won't happen with the `case_when` that i wrote for you, because the final `TRUE~"None"` will apply to any rows not meeting the other conditions

Comment: great glad it worked.